# How to check if a particular disk sector contains data?

Tags: hard-drive, usb-storage, sectors

[Kangaru USB mass storage device duplicator](https://www.kanguru.com/index.php/duplicators/usb-duplicators/11-target-kanguru-usb-duplicatortm-with-built-in-hard-drive)

In the product description, one of the features it boasts is "Brief Mode", wherein it only copies those sectors that contain data. My question is, **how does it know which sectors contain data?** Is it file-system aware (it does mention that it supports most major file-systems)? If so, will it be able to duplicate USB drives that are encrypted using full volume encryption (in "brief mode")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very likely that the particular device in question is using filesystem metadata to figure out which sectors are in use by the filesystem.